# How does the ajaxStop function work internally?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm sorry if this isn't the right place to ask this.

I know for sure per the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) of the `ajaxStop()` function that :

> Whenever an AJAX request is completed, jQuery checks whether there are any other outstanding AJAX requests, if there are no requests remaining, then jQuery triggers the ajaxStop event.

What I can't seem to understand is *how* is it doing that internally. How does it know that all ajax requests have ended in a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a global ajax counter `jQuery.active`

Each request increments it  when it starts and decrements when it completes.

If it is zero when it completes `ajaxStop` is triggered

Here's the [line in the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/e743cbd28553267f955f71ea7248377915613fd9/src/ajax.js#L816) that triggers it

Comment: Would you kindly give me a source? Either from a documentation or their code.

Comment: FYI - I wsn't sure myself. Found it very quickly by searching `"ajaxStop"` in the github repo

Comment: I did search that as well, but I couldn't find where is `ajaxStop` function in itself defined, the one that gets triggered. But your answer answered some of my wonderings so it's good enough I guess.